# Spring JMS Message Listener fails to find JNDI lookup

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, websphere, jndi

The application uses Spring JMS Listener to connect to JMS Queues and it is   deployed in WAS 8.5.x.
Using spring application context xml, [`org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html) bean is initialized with `ConnectionFactory`, Destination as [`JndiObjectFactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiObjectFactoryBean.html).

Inside `MessageListener` class `onMessage()` method, the code is trying to look JNDI reference using `InitialContext`, code snippet is below,

```java
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
String name = (String) ic.lookup("jndiName");
```

Application throws below exception while processing a message.

> Exception : javax.naming.ConfigurationException:  A JNDI operation on
>   a "java:" name cannot be completed because the server runtime is not
>   able to associate the operation's thread with any J2EE application
>   component.  This condition can occur when the JNDI client using the
>   "java:" name is not executed on the thread of a server application
>   request.  Make sure that a J2EE application does not execute JNDI
>   operations on "java:" names within static code blocks or in threads
>   created by that J2EE application.  Such code does not necessarily run
>   on the thread of a server application request and therefore is not
>   supported by JNDI operations on "java:" names. [Root exception is
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/cache not found in
>   context "java:".]

My understanding is, the Message Listener threads are created by the application during initialization under J2EE Web Container. The code is trying to access JNDI resource defined in WebSphere server, but not able to get the handle to Initial Context.

Note: resource-ref tag with this JNDI entry is included in web.xml.

```xml
<resource-ref id="configCache">
  <description>Resource reference to Configuration Cache</description>
  <res-ref-name>cache/config</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>com.ibm.websphere.cache.DistributedMap</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us how is it defined in web.xml.

Comment: If message listeners threads are application generated, then they will not have access to the JEE context, thus the error. You would have to use external JNDI name , not java:comp/env, or even better use classic MessageDriven beans. Or  somehow configure Spring to use server managed threads.

Comment: Here is the config in web.xml   <resource-ref id="configCache">
  <description>Resource reference to Configuration Cache</description>
  <res-ref-name>cache/config</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>com.ibm.websphere.cache.DistributedMap</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
 </resource-ref>

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem.

Here is the solution,
In web.xml I defined the Resource reference of type com.ibm.websphere.cache.DistributedMap. I created the JNDI (of type Object Cache) in WebSphere Admin console and map it to this resource during deployment.

```
 <resource-ref id="sampleCacheName">
        <description>Resource reference to Cache</description>
        <res-ref-name>cache/sampleCache</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>com.ibm.websphere.cache.DistributedMap</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

In my spring context xml, I defined the JMS Listener bean which takes Task Executor object from default WebSphere work manager,

```
 <bean id="jmsContainerSampleEvent"
        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="myConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="destination" ref="myQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="myEventListener" />
        <property name ="concurrentConsumers" value ="5"/>
    <property name ="maxConcurrentConsumers" value ="20"/>
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="workManagerTaskExecutor" />
</bean>


<bean id="workManagerTaskExecutor"
          class="org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor"
          p:workManagerName="wm/default" />
```